How do I display strings and variables on the same line? It's more than just numbers
The calculator I'm writing this code for is a TI-84 Plus CE, I've tried using output and as you see in the code, I have also tried turning the variables into strings:
Lbl 7
Input "WAHT IS THE RADIUS? ",A
Input "WHAT IS THE HEIGHT? ",C
(πA²)→B
2B+(2πA)H→S
2π*A*C→L
Disp "WORK:"
Disp "(π",toString(A),"²)"
Disp "PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE"
Pause 
Disp "2",toString(B),"+(2π",A,")",toString(H)
Disp "PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE"
Pause 
Disp "2π*",toString(A),"*",toString(C)
Disp "PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE"
Pause 
Disp "ANSWERS:"
Disp "B: ",B
Disp "LA: ",L
Disp "SA: ",S
Stop

What I want is for each display call to display on one line each

The Disp command treats commas as new lines, so Disp "HELLO","WORLD"
will print:
HELLO
WORLD

However, if the commas are replaced with plus characters, the Disp command will print the two strings on the same line: Disp "HELLO"+"WORLD" will print:HELLOWORLD.
Note that if you use the plus character between a string and a number, Disp will treat it as a comma: Disp "HI"+5 will print:
HI
5

Alternatively, you can use the output command:
Output(8,1,"HI")
Output(8,3,5)

Will print HI5 on line 8 (counting from 1).
